# Magento 2 catalog search?

Tags: magento2, product, catalogsearch

Magento 2 how to implement **catalog search** programmatically.

I need categories and product details.

Please provide reference links if any.

Please find the screenshot :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EX: http://testsite.com/filename.php?q={yoursearchterm}

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$appState = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\App\State::class);
$layerResolver = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver::class);
$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
$layerResolvers = $layerResolver->create('search');
$layerResolvers1 = $layerResolver->get();
$productCollection = $layerResolvers1->getProductCollection();

echo "Search layered navigation :<br>";
echo "products count == ".count($productCollection)."<br>";
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    echo "Name : ".$product->getName()." Price : ".$product->getPrice()."<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for u r reply but how to get categories  here?

Comment: Just add the categories on Magento Admin